# How to create multiple different lags

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to create new variables in a dataframe that represent multiple lags. I have one time series in it right now "series" and I would like to create 10 different variables, each representing a certain lag of "series". So the resulting data frame would have the original variable "series," plus 10 variables named (1, 2, 3, 4, ... 10) that would represent that number of lags. I am currently trying this on a for loop:

```
for (i in 1:max.lag){
  lag.death$"i" <- lag(tscampos, i)
}
```

But after reading here, I suspect I might want to use one of the apply functions? Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to pad the sides with zeroes when you get out of the time-range? `*apply` might be a solution, but if I were you I would rather write a function that would do the job for you any time you'd need instead of storing 10 lagged versions of the same serie.. wait a minut ;)

Comment: Wait a minut, are you talking about the actual R's `lag` function? If yes, this function returns a lagged "time-serie object" which, once stuck in a data.frame, is exactly the same as the original one. If you really need to store 10 lagged version of "series", then put them into a list with `lapply(0:9,lag,x=lag.death$series)`.

Comment: I used to have this problem before. When I want to use lags in my analysis, I tend to think of adding new variables for each lag I need. However, I found that for most of R functions we use in time-series, it has the ability to deal with lags and you will find the number of lags as an option in the function. So all what you need is your original variable along with dates to represent the time series.

Answer (score 2):

There you go: this function will allow you getting a lagged version of your serie whenever you'll need it. ('better than storing each lagged replicate of the same serie in 10 different columns I find)

```
lag.death = data.frame(series = floor(runif(10,0,100)));
lag.death$serie

lagit4me = function(serie,lag){
    n = length(serie);
    pad = rep(0,lag);
    return(c(pad,serie)[1:n]);
}


lagit4me(lag.death$serie,1);
lagit4me(lag.death$serie,3);
```

'can tweak it then to allow negative lags or etc.

( But if you really need it: )

```
allIn1 = lapply(0:10,lagit4me,serie=lag.death$series);
allIn1 = data.frame(allIn1);
names(allIn1) = 0:10;
allIn1
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: Just fyi, you don't need any of those semicolons

Comment: No I don't, 'just a habit. I like to see the end of my instructions :)

Comment: Thanks. I do actually need to store the lags as new variables. The second block of code doesn't run for me - trying to assign allIn1 as a dataframe throws an error (arguments imply different number of rows)

Comment: This is because I didn't make `lagit4me` able to check the final length of the lagged serie, which must be `n` at all times but might be more if the lag is big. I'll add this check tonight, or perhaps you'll do it before ;)

Comment: Here you go (function edited), does it work better now?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use purrr::map(), similar to lapply() above.  This uses dplyr::lag(), instead of lagit4me()

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

num.lags <- 0:10 

list.lags <- 
  purrr::map(
    .x = num.lags,
    .f = ~ dplyr::lag(series, .x)
  )
```

Note, you need to name the list elements to coerce to a data_frame

```
chr.lags <- paste0("lag_", num.series.lags)
names(list.model.subset.lags) <- chr.lags

tbl.model.subset.lags <- 
  dplyr::bind_rows(list.model.subset.lags)
```

This produces a tbl with 11 variables, the input variable (lag_0) and 10 lagged variables (with NAs)

```
print(tbl.model.subset.lags)
```